# NullPointerException not being caught

Tags: java, reflection, nullpointerexception

I am using Java reflection as such:

```
try {
    method.invoke(someObject);
  } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | NullPointerException e) {
    //Do something
  }
```

`method` is retrieved from iterating through `getMethods()` from `"Set<Method> getMethods = new HashSet<Method>(Arrays.asList(curObject.getClass().getMethods()))"`

`someObject` is not *null*, but within the method call it makes a call to something that results in a `NullPointerException`.

However, the code still errors out with a `NullPointerException` with the stack trace pointing back to "method.invoke(someObject);".

Why doesn't the *catch* work? Has it something to do with reflection?

Comment: How have you defined `method`, paste your entire code along with the entire stack trace.

Comment: Set<Method> getMethods = new HashSet<Method>(Arrays.asList(curObject.getClass().getMethods()));
 Is how i get a set of methods. I then iterate through it. I would like to paste it but I am not sure if that is against policy

Comment: Not in comments! Please update your question instead!

Comment: And how do you know that an exception was thrown when your catch is empty and thus all error information is immediately discarded?

Comment: Because the program halts and nullpointer exception is shown in the console

Comment: Any exception thrown by the method being invoked will be wrapped in an InvocationTargetException, so if you’re getting a NullPointerException which is not the cause of an InvocationTargetException, it pretty much has to be because `method` is null.

Comment: Because the invoked method can contain arbitrary code, including something like `try { … } catch(NullPointerException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); System.exit(0); }`

Answer (score 2):

i think you should try this:

```
 try
 { 
   // your code may error occures !!
 }
 catch(NullPointerException e)
{
//do your work here
}
catch(InvocationTargetException e)
{
//do your work here
}
catch(IllegalAccessException e)
{
//do your work here
}
catch(IllegalArgumentException e)
{
//do your work here
}
catch(Exception e)
{
//do your work here
}
```

here all your Exceptions catch in multiple catch blocks.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not catching the exception is that it's not a `NullPointerException`, but a `com.mapp.node.logging.exception.ConstructingFatalThrowableException`. This exception is being thrown with the message (which follows the exception's name) *"java.lang.NullPointerException"* and that's the source of confusion. Try to catch the `ConstructingFatalThrowableException` instead of the *NPE* and see if it works.

---

Also, note that you shouldn't be catching a `NullPointerException`. It is a `RuntimeException` and this group of exceptions usually indicates a programming error, in which case you shouldn't "handle" it, because if you knew to expect it, you should have avoided the error. See what the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html) say:

> Runtime exceptions represent problems that are the result of a
>   programming problem, and as such, the **API client code cannot
>   reasonably be expected to recover from them or to handle them in any
>   way**. Such problems include arithmetic exceptions, such as dividing by
>   zero; pointer exceptions, such as trying to access an object through a
>   null reference (...)

With this in mind, just avoid the `NullPointerException`. Check an example below:

```
if(var!= null) {
    //Normal code here 
} 
else {
    //Handle the null pointer here
}
```

Comment: This code is meant to test for bad code. I want to use reflection to call code that may contain errors and have it report back to the user.

Comment: Actually, I think you are wrong. A *null pointer* isn't the same as a `NullPointerException`. The later might be caused by the first, but it doesn't mean that a *null pointer* can't exist without an exception being thrown. If `var` is *null*, then it doesn't hold a reference to any object, thus, it's a *null pointer*. The docs say, as quoted above, that you shouldn't handle a `NullPointerException`. So, I'm proposing that you handle a possible *null pointer* instead of letting the exception be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

If I read the stack trace correctly, it is not a NullPointerException being thrown, but a `com.mapp.node.logging.exception.ConstructingFatalThrowableException` with the message (and probably the cause) "`java.lang.NullPointerException`".
The first line of a `NullPointerExcpetion` stack trace would actually start with `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

To check this, you could just add `ConstructingFatalThrowableException` to your `catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a NPE: it's a `com.mapp.node.logging.exception.ConstructingFatalThrowableException` thrown by some funky code instrumented to intervene when building NPEs.

Read the stack from bottom-up:

```
com.mapp.node.logging.exception.ConstructingFatalThrowableException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mapp.server.util.ExceptionInstrumentationUtil.handleFatalThrowable(ExceptionInstrumentationUtil.java:212)
    at com.mapp.server.util.ExceptionInstrumentationUtil.access$000(ExceptionInstrumentationUtil.java:32)
    at com.mapp.server.util.ExceptionInstrumentationUtil$2.sample(ExceptionInstrumentationUtil.java:164)
    at com.mapp.server.util.ExceptionInstrumentationUtil$2.sample(ExceptionInstrumentationUtil.java:160)
    at com.google.monitoring.runtime.instrumentation.ConstructorInstrumenter.invokeSamplers(ConstructorInstrumenter.java:207)
    at java.lang.RuntimeException.<init>(RuntimeException.java:52)
    at java.lang.NullPointerException.<init>(NullPointerException.java:60)
```

The thread is at `NullPointerException.java:60` where there is a call to `java.lang.RuntimeException.<init>` (ie. the superclass constructor) where (at `RuntimeException.java:52`) there's what the JVM is instrumented to think of as a call to `com.google.monitoring.runtime.instrumentation.ConstructorInstrumenter.invokeSamplers` (I believe it takes the place of a `super()`?).

Anyhow - your exception is thrown in `ExceptionInstrumentationUtil.java:212`.